# Verify connection in PHP MySQL without opening any schema/DB

Tags: php, html

This is my PHP code to check the connection but it isn't working. Can someone help me, please?

```
<?php   
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";     
$link= new mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">";
echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle\"></span> Connection to MySQL failed: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
mysql_close($link);
exit;
}
// make 'redes' the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('redes', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: use mysqli* functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Stop using `MySQL_` functions. These functions are deprecated and have been removed in PHP 7.

1) If you are using PHP 7, your functions are not working as they're not recognised. They have been removed. STOP using `MySql_` regardless of what version of PHP you are running.

2) You are blending `Object Orientated` and `Procedural` syntax at the same time, this will cause you lots of errors, it's as if you're talking to someone in German and French at the same time -- it's extremely hard to understand and generates bad syntax.

### Solution

- Use just *One* Syntax style; given your example this will probably be ***Procedural*** and so you can do:

  ```
   $link= new mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
         ^^^^^ Remove this word.
  ```
- `if (!$connection) {` The value of `$connection` is never set, so this `if` will always run.
- Transfer over from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` procedural syntax and functions.

Please [read the documentation for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

## A rewrite of your code:

The selection of the database can be combined into the connection establishment call, at the start of the codeblock. The most notable thing to, er, note, is that `MySQLi_` functions almost always require a reference to the connection you want feedback from, such as in this instance: `$link`. So that processes such as `mysqli_error()` is told specifically *which connection* to give error data from.

```
<?php   
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ''; // password should be in sigle quotes to
                // avoid certain strings being accidentally escaped 
                // or changed such as if your password contains a $ sign.     
$db = 'redes';
$link= mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if (!$link) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
    echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span> 
         Connection to MySQL failed: ".mysqli_error($link)."</div>";
    mysql_close($link);
    exit;
}

//future changing of the database as needed:
$newDb = "newDb";
if(mysqli_select_db ( $link , $newDb)){
    print "db changed!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `new` keyword,

```
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";

    $link =  mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);// remove `new` 
    if (!$link) {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">";
        echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle\"></span> Connection to MySQL failed: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
        mysql_close($link);
        exit;
    }
```

Check the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '';

/*** mysql password ***/
$databaseName = 'ads';



// check connection, prepare query and execute it and stop script if something was wrong
// when something was wrong catch error (exception) and show it
// $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// PDOException

try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);        
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    die("Connection error: " . $exc->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's try this...
it will work

check the line no four i have removed new keyword and if (!$link) instead of if (!$connection)

```
<?php
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";    
    $link = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
   echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">";
  echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle\"></span>Connection to MySQL failed: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
 mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: can you explain what you've changed and why that makes it work?

Comment: check the line no four i have removed new keyword and
if (!$link)  instead of   if (!$connection)